# Polynomial square rule for a big polynomial

Tags: calculus, computational-mathematics, square-numbers

I have the following polynomial square to solve

$(a+b(cos(2 \pi \nu )-sin(2 \pi \nu ))+c(cos(4 \pi \nu )-sin(4 \pi \nu )))^{2}$

For three factors I would use $(a+bx+cy)^{2} = (a^{2}+bx^2+cy^2+2bx+2cy)$ but in my case I have 5 factors and I don't know how to continue for a solution.

Thanks to all

Comment: Actually, $$(a+bx+cy)^2 = a^2 +b^2x^2 +c^2y^2 +2abx+2bcxy+2acy $$ In your problem, try treating them as three terms first and then expand again.

Comment: @Tavish thanks for your answer... I haven't understand... 1) my role for the polynomial three terms, one is a constant, square is wrong? 2) how can I solve my square with $sin()$ and $cos()$ in my request?

Comment: Let me post an answer.

Comment: how can I treating them like three terms? I never does something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, $x=2\pi \nu$. We have, $$\big( a+b(\cos x -\sin x) +c(\cos 2x -\sin 2x) \big)^2 \\ =a^2 +b^2(\cos x-\sin x)^2 +c^2(\cos 2x -\sin 2x)^2 +2ab(\cos x-\sin x) +2bc(\cos x-\sin x)(\cos 2x-\sin 2x) +2ac(\cos 2x-\sin 2x) \\ = a^2 +b^2(1-\sin2x) +c^2(1-\sin 4x)+2ab(\cos x-\sin x) +2bc\big( (\cos x \cos 2x +\sin x \sin 2x) -(\sin 2x \cos x +\sin x \cos 2x)\big)+2ac(\cos 2x-\sin 2x) \\ = a^2 +b^2(1-\sin 2x)+c^2(1-\sin 4x) +2ab(\cos x-\sin x)+2bc(\cos x-\sin 3x) +2ac(\cos 2x -\sin 2x) \\ \vdots $$ Hopefully you can do the simplification.

Comment: Thank you so much... one question, I have write $2bc$ like this: $2bc[cos(x)cos(2x) - cos(x)sin(2x)-cos(2x)sin(x)+sin(x)sin(2x)]$
Is like your? and why have you divided in this form? Thx

Comment: can you explain me the simplification on $2bc$? It's the only thing that I haven't understand... I try with trigonometric function but I wrong something

Comment: You’ll find these identities helpful: $$\cos(a-b) = \cos a \cos b +\sin a \sin b \\ \sin(a+b) =\sin a \cos b + \sin b \cos a$$ You can arrange the terms however you like, the end result will be the same.

Comment: I have multiplied, is the same?